# Rails - attr_accessor :- read the attribute value instead of the function overriding it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `Customer` that accepts a virtual attribute `opening_balance`. Code looks something like this:

```
model Customer < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :opening_balance

  has_one :ledger_account

  after_create :open_ledger_account

  def opening_balance
    ledger_account.opening_balance if ledger_account.present?
  end

  private

  def open_ledger_account
    create_ledger_account!(opening_balance: self.opening_balance)
  end
```

But the issue here is `self.opening_balance` is calling the method defined in the class not the value stored in attr_accessor's opening_balance attribute.

I tried one more solution:

```
def open_ledger_account
  create_ledger_account!(opening_balance: self.read_attribute(:opening_balance))
end
```

But this also doesn't work.

How to read the value stored in the actual attribute? Any help would be appreciated. I am using rails 5.1.

Thanks!

Comment: `opening_balance` attribute is available before the save. After saving the customer object, inside the callback it only gets the attributes associated to newly created customer object. 
I would suggest you to do it using nested forms where in custom model you can get the `opening_balance` as a nested attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor` defines a instance variable and a method to access it (read/write).

So the easy way is to write:

```
def open_ledger_account
  create_ledger_account!(opening_balance: @opening_balance)
end
```

The `read_attribute` would only work if `opening_balance` was an attribute in the database on `Customer`.

Comment: `attribute_accessor` **does not** define a instance variable. It just creates a setter and getter method. Instance variables are "defined" whenever when you first assign a value to them. So calling the setter method would "define" the variable.

Comment: Obviously true, because in ruby one has no other way to "define" an instance-variable, then by assigning a value. My description was intentionally concise and simplified to keep the answer short and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand that `attr_accessor` does not define instance variables. It just creates setter and getter methods. What `attr_accessor :name` does is:

```
class Person
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(value)
    @name = value
  end
end
```

Now you can access the instance variable from the outside:

```
p = Person.new
p.name = 'Jane'
puts p.name
```

And you can also access the instance variable from the inside by using the getter method instead of `@name`:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
  def hello
    "hello my name is: #{name}"
  end
end
```

`attr_accessor` does not "define" a instance variable. There is no declaration of members/attributes in Ruby like in for example Java. An instance variables is declared when it is first set. Accessing an instance variable that has not been assigned a value returns nil.

So whats happing here:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :opening_balance
  # ...
  def opening_balance
    ledger_account.opening_balance if ledger_account.present?
  end
end
```

Is that you are overwriting the getter created by `attr_accessor`. If you want to access the instance variable itself just use `@opening_balance`.

### However...

You should just use [delegate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) instead:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ledger_account
  delegate :opening_balance, to: :ledger_account
end
```

Comment: I love the delegate suggestion. My guess is that the `attr_accessor` is there because when creating a new customer, one can immediately enter the opening-balance in the same form. Using the delegate will unfortunately _break_ that solution; but imho that would ultimately lead to a cleaner solution, and let e.g. let the controller handle 1) the creation of the new customer, and 2) the ledger-account, instead of letting the model handle it.